# Snap.svg - Absolute Transforms Not Working

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

How to transform Element Absolute transform
[this bug](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/97) still not fixed, i think!

 HTML :

```
<svg id="svgout" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 800 800"></svg>
```

JS:

```
var paper = Snap("#svgout"); 

var r = paper.rect(200,200,100,100,20,20).
r.attr({ stroke: '#123456', 'strokeWidth': 20, fill: 'red', 'opacity': 0.3 });

rclone = r.clone();

rclone.transform( 'T-100,0'); // 'T' not work !
```

[this demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eyaapv)

```
rclone.transform( 'T-100,0'); // 'T' not work !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that absolute transforms work, however, Snap doesn't differentiate between relative and absolute transforms any more. There is no difference between 'T' and 't', unlike Raphael. Your example does an absolute transform fine for me.

So if you want to absolute transform, just give it any transform, like in your example. If you want a relative transform, you will need to keep track yourself and build the transform string, or check what transform is in place already and use that to add a transform to it.